# Issue with finding general solution to recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, homogeneous-equation

I need to find the general solution to the recurrence relation:
$a_n  = 4a_{n-1} - 4a_{n-2} + 6 \cdot 2^n$ for all $n \geq 2$, given the intial conditons $a_0 = 9$ and $a_1=36$

I know that this is a nonhomogenrous equation so the final solution is going to be a combination of a homogeneous $h_n$ and a particular solution $p_n$

I know that you can rearrange this to give:
$a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} = 6 \cdot 2^n$

Computing the characteristic equation to find $h_n$ gives $x^2-4x+4$ with the solution $x=2$

Here is where I get confused:

does $p_n = c2^n$? If so,

substitute to into above to get:

$c2^n - 4c2^{n-1} + 4c2^{n-2} = 6\cdot2^n$

Cancel out the $2^{n-2}$: which gives,

$4c - 8c + 4c = 24$, which can not be solved.

I'm not entirely sure where my error lies, I can not come to an understanding of where I am going wrong.

Comment: Take care : $x=2$ is a double root. So ....

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not too sure what to do when there is a double root. My lecture notes don't address this, probably why I am very confused.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898819/how-to-deal-with-linear-recurrence-that-its-characteristic-polynomial-has-multi